# How to convert a N columns table to two column table in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

How to convert a table of multiple columns to a two columns table in excel. As shown in the image the two-column table should be based on the first column of the multiple column table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use these steps

- select the data,
- get & transform tab on `data` menu
- from table
- data will be opened in `power query` window
- select columns 2 to column 5, at once
- right click, use `unpivot`
- save and load

see the following screenGIFs

[image]

**Edit** in view of comments below

To add `null` values to output you can do following workaround

- replace null values from any non-existent value say `-`
- then unpivot
- see the following GIF

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing the GIF. It was easy to understand. In the new table, it's missing the null cells from the old table. Is it possible to get the null values also?

Comment: Glad that it helped.  See revised answer to handle `nulls`.  Please upvote and accept, if my answer helped you.  Thanks